# How to create executable application to using opencv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, exe

I am greener in Python .I have design a small application for my personal project . But the problem is that when i use it on python then it's ok after create a executable(exe) application by **pyinstaller** then it's show "**Fatal error"** and **"cam returned  -1"** my python project name is cam.py.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOrtL.png)
 I don't know what's the problem of this application .

and my code is below:

```
 import cv2
 import numpy
 face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
 cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 while True :
     ret,frame = cam.read()
     gray = cv2.cvtColor (frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
     faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5)
     for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
         cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
         cv2.imshow("LubnaX(NSL2)",frame)

     k = cv2.waitKey(10)
     if k==27:
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: please any one help me

Comment: Can you add in some print statements to see if the problem is with the actual opening of the camera, the grabbing of some of the frames, or releasing the camera?